# destroy not working in java

Tags: java, excel, process, destroy

I have created a simple java program to open an excel file and write data to it, once the data is written I then proceed to open the file to view the spreadsheet:

```
String[] cmdarray=new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\*******\\********\\******.xls"}; 
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec(cmdarray);
```

as part of the learning curve I then try to close the file 10 secs later with:

```
process.destroy();
```

but this isn't closing the window.
Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? Thank you.

```
private static void OpenExcel() throws IOException {

            //Find the File and open it
            String[] cmdarray=new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","C:\\Users\\Jason\\Documents\\*********\\*********\\********.xls"}; 
            Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process process = runTime.exec(cmdarray);

            try{    
            //Delay
             TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);

        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Handle exception
            }
            //Close Excel
            System.out.println("Closing Excel");
            process.destroy();

            }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the reason could be well-known [JDK bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4770092):

> The fundamental problem here is that, unlike Unix, Windows does that
>   maintain parent-child relationships between processes. A process can
>   kill its own immediate children, but unless you make other
>   arrangements to obtain the information, can't kill any
>   'grand-children' because it has no way of finding them.

You can try with direct execution of Excel, not via cmd:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\full\\path\\to\\excel.exe C:\\file.xls");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am not sure what you mean by a direct execution of excel, could you expand on that please?

Comment: I see... so I would include the path to the actual excel program and then immediately after that include the (full?) path to the .xls file?

Comment: ok, I have implemented your suggestion and now the .destroy is working but when it is opening Excel it gives a warning that the file could not be found? I supplemented C:\\file.xls with my own. Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: I have solved the problem....it was whitespace in my file name.xls when changed to filename.xls it works? is that a common error that you know of? thanks for your help.